# Como enviar um socket após o recebimento do resultado do socket anterior? Flutter Dart

Tags: socket, flutter

Estou realizando uma comunicação por socket usando flutter em um equipamento Modbus, preciso enviar várias leituras no equipamento, porém uma sobrepõe a outra antes da resposta do socket anterior. Tentei de várias formas, porém não consigo disparar automaticamente. Apenas em cliques seguidos em um botão. Tentei adicionar um loop. Mas ele só envia várias requisições e só obtém a última resposta. Porém clique a clique funciona. Alguém me ajuda??

Estou utilizando a classe IO do Dart e Flutter.

```
sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));

Uint8List request = preparaCMDUint8list(counter, 3, 1, '16', null);

await Future.wait([xhandle(request)]).then((_) {
  print('acabou o envio $_');
  // sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
  // setState(() {});
}).whenComplete(() {});


Uint8List request = preparaCMDUint8list(counter, 3, 1, '17', null);

await Future.wait([xhandle(request)]).then((_) {
  print('acabou o envio $_');
  // sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
  // setState(() {});
}).whenComplete(() {});
```

Esta é a função que envia o socket

```
Future xhandle(Uint8List _request) async {
  conectou = false;
  await Socket.connect(connectionProvider.getEnderecoIpConnect(),
          int.parse(await connectionProvider.getEnderecoPorta()))
      .then((Socket sock) {
    conectou = true;

    _socket = sock;
    _socket.listen(_onData,
        onError: errorHandler, onDone: doneHandler, cancelOnError: true);
    sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  }).then((_) {
    conectou = true;
    print('Enviou, then do socket: $_request');
    print(_request); // so that your code runs AFTER the TCP/IP connection
    // _socket.write(_request);
    //counter++;
    print('Passou no timer eviou o request');
    print(DateTime.now());
    sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    _socket.add(_request);
    sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 400));

    _socket.close();
  }).whenComplete(() {
    if (!conectou) {
      conectou = false;
      _socket.close();
      print('erro do sockets');
      sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    }
  });
}
```

Existem mai funções que acredito não serem necessárias, como a `onDone`, `onData` e `onError`

os Sleep são tentativas de demorar o código para uma requisição não engolir a outra

Comment: O que custa editar uma pergunta e esperar a mesma ser reaberta? Tente não poluir o site...

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço o equipamento Modbus, mas em comunicação com equipamentos é normal que a cada pacote de dados enviado você precisa esperar uma resposta reconhecendo o recebimento.

Se for o caso, seu código não faz isso. Você anexa um callback ao seu socket mas não encontrei no código uma sincronização que permita que o próximo envio ocorra apenas após recebimento da resposta anterior.

Fora isso você precisa fazer a programação assíncrona trabalhar para você. Um método marcado como `async` serve para não precisar usar a API `Future` (chamadas a `then()`), então misturar os dois pode ser a causa dos seus problemas.

Tentei ajustar seu método `xhandle` para trabalhar dessa forma. No início ele abre o socket apenas se ele já não está aberto. Então ele envia o pacote de dados do parâmetro `_request` e imediatamente aguarda uma resposta usando `await for`.

Estou assumindo que o equipamento envia respostas apenas após receber um comando via socket. Se o equipamento pode aleatoriamente enviar outros pacotes então sua abordagem com `_socket.listen` é mais adequada, mas nesse caso precisa haver algum tipo de sincronia em que, após enviar um pacote, você espera a resposta em seu callback passado no `_socket.listen` e apenas libera o envio de um novo pacote quando o anterior obter resposta.

Perceba que removi a parte de fechar o socket do método `xhandle`. A ideia é que, uma vez que o socket seja aberto, permaneça aberto até você não precisar mais dele. Sendo assim o fechamento do socket deve ficar em outro lugar, provavelmente na saída da tela que chama essa funcionalidade.

Segue exemplo:

```
Socket _socket;
Future xhandle(Uint8List _request) async { 
  // ??= só atribui um novo valor a _socket se esse for nulo, senão ignora a chamada
  _socket ??= await Socket.connect(connectionProvider.getEnderecoIpConnect(),
          int.parse(await connectionProvider.getEnderecoPorta()));

  // Envia um pacote de dados via socket
  _socket.add(_request);

  // Aguarda uma resposta que deve acontecer 
  // como resultado do envio acima
  try {
    await for (final response in _socket) {
      // Processa response.
      // Se response foi o desejado para de esperar
      if (checaResposta(response)) {
        break;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Houve erro ao obter resposta, trata aqui
  }
}
```

Comment: Então, não resolvi desta forma, eu criei um timer que executa a cada 1 segundo. Então dá tempo de enviar e receber o pacote. E aí confirmar o pacote recebido com uma variável global de controle. Eu disparo o próximo envio. E assim vai até fazer todos envios e recebimentos. Talvez seja gambiarra, mas funciona.

Comment: Entendi. Se você não está esperando nenhuma resposta seria bom então adicionar uma resposta à sua própria pergunta descrevendo sua solução e marcando sua resposta como aceita, para que outras pessoas achem mais facilmente a solução.